# Creating Pseudocode and determining its time complexity

Tags: for-loop, time-complexity, pseudocode

This is a programming question about basics:

How to write a simple pseudocode of a function that takes as input n grades then compute the average of the grades.

What is its time complexity ?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to deal with pseudo-code.

> Depending on the writer, pseudocode may therefore vary widely in style, from a near-exact imitation of a real programming language at one extreme, to a description approaching formatted prose at the other. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode)

Good General guidelines for instance can be found [here](https://users.csc.calpoly.edu/%7Ejdalbey/SWE/pdl_std.html). The idea is to be concise yet clear and precise. For instance, newer use the C-style affectation symbol "=", prefer to use ":=" instead.

Answering to the question:

```
FUNCTION: compute_grades_average()
    INPUTS: 
        n: int # number of grades
        grades: Array[float] # grades, with floats between 0 and 1
    OUTPUTS:
        average: float
    BODY:
        sum := 0
        FOR grade in grades:
            sum := sum + grade
        average := sum / n
        RETURN average
```

There is only one loop of size n, so the time complexity is O(n).